# Cartoon about 2 guys (one named Sam) and a girl

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon

I don't remember how long ago exactly, like 2 or 3 years, I watched a show on Netflix about, I think, teens: 2 guys one was kind of an idiot and loves sumo, the other one was an inventor, I think his name was Sam and a girl who was very smart. They do some kind of supernatural adventure like go to a different world where there are weird creatures.
I'm not sure but I think it was a video game before an animated series
I remember in one episode that something happened to the girl and she turned into kind of an idiot and the two guys had to write some long essay for her.

Comment: This is incredibly brief can you not remember anything else about it at all? Also you mention "supernatural adventures" but then say nothing else about that. As that is the only part of this that would make it on topic could you expand on that at all? Remember the more details you include the more likely someone is to find this for you. Please [edit] anything else you remember about this into your question.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you recall where you saw it?  (Like what service or channel?)

Comment: I'd be surprised if this was it (hence the comment, not an answer) but this has some resemblance to [_Green Eggs and Ham_](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4651448/?ref_=ttep_ep_tt). I can't find reference to the episode you mention though and I haven't watched it to be sure.

Comment: What type of cartoon was it? Animated picture, or 3D?

Comment: https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/The_Bite-Sized_Adventures_of_Sam_Sandwich

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_Rhino_Junior_High

Answer (score 4):

Could this be [*Cloudy with a Chance of Meatballs: The TV series*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4123482/)?

It features a *girl* named Sam and an inventor boy named Flint and is set in a high school, which potentially accounts for the essay-writing element.

Comment: thats not it but thanks anyway